# cron jobs partly run

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I have a simple cron job set up in cron like so:

```
## Uncomment for running the logs
55 1 * * * /hn/all_fetcher
```

all_fetcher is very simple

```
/hn/fetcher hnlive@node4.hypernumbers.com
echo "fired node4 fetcher"
/hn/fetcher hnlive@node5.hypernumbers.com
echo "fired node5 fetcher"
/hn/fetcher hnlive@hypernumbers.com
echo "fired main fetcher"
/hn/fetcher hnlive@node2.hypernumbers.com
echo "fired node2 fetcher"
/hn/fetcher hnlive@node3.hypernumbers.com
echo "fired node3 fetcher"
```

Not all these jobs run. The first 4 do, if I change the order the last one fails.

Debugging cron is a world of pain :( Any suggestions as to how to reliably do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you run this script by hand and not by cron? Same results?

Cron should be sending emails with all output from the script being run. You can have these sent to you by setting the `MAILTO` variable at the top of your crontab, e.g.

```
MAILTO=john.doe@example.net
## Uncomment for running the logs
55 1 * * * /hn/all_fetcher
```